# Read file line by line and delete that line

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read file line by line and parallelly delete those lines.
For that, I have written this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
fielpos="/Desktop/Folder/fiel.txt"
LineNoCtr=0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "Text read from file: $line"
        LineNoCtr=expr $LineNoCtr + 1
        echo "line no is:$LineNoCtr"
        sed -i "/$LineNoCtr/"'d' $fielpos
        sleep 1
done < "$fielpos"
```

Is this the correct method?

Comment: How about using sed for this task?

Comment: What is the task you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a walk-though:

```
#!/bin/bash
fielpos="/Desktop/Folder/fiel.txt"
```

Use `declare -i lineno=0` here: a) usual naming conventions, b) declare it as an integer variable instead of a text variable

```
LineNoCtr=0
```

`IFS=''` is not necessary here, `[[ -n "$line" ]]` also, because it would terminate the loop for empty lines.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "Text read from file: $line"
```

change to `let ++lineno` according to the `declare -i` line

```
        LineNoCtr=expr $LineNoCtr + 1
```

change to `$LineNoCtr` to `$lineno`

```
        echo "line no is:$LineNoCtr"
```

change to `sed -i "1 d" "$fielpos"` because

- you use `"$fielpos"` below which means you might expect whitespace in the filename.
- `sed "/42/d"` would delete lines which *contains* the text `42` whereas `sed "42d"` deletes the 42nd line. BUT: Even if `lineno` is `42` you have already deleted those line in the previous iterations. So you always have to delete just the first line.

  ```
      sed -i "/$LineNoCtr/"'d' $fielpos
      sleep 1
  ```

  done < "$fielpos"

Putting the pieces together:

```
#!/bin/bash
fielpos="y"
declare -i lineno=0
while read -r line; do
        echo "Text read from file: $line"
        let ++lineno
        echo "line no is:$lineno"
        sed -i "1 d" "$fielpos"
        sleep 1
done < "$fielpos"
```

Final notes:

- If the file is HUGE then this method is quite slow, because each iteration will write almost all of the file.
- This will not work on Windows because `< "$fielpos"` will lock the file and therefore `sed` cannot write it. Unix/Linux will work though.

Comment: i had changed the logic, instead of deleting line by using line number i have switched to deleting by matching string.
`sed -i "/$line/"'d' $fielpos`